# The corresponding web pages are not loading when the link is tapped in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, hyperlink

In my Xamarin forms project, we show the HTML data on the UI using a webview.

Using below code I am showing html content on UI:

```
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = description;//HTML Content
web_view.Source = htmlSource;
```

Using below code I'm parsing the video links:

```
    var allMatches = Regex.Matches(description, "<iframe.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match match in allMatches)
{
    string sourceData = Regex.Match(match.ToString(), "<iframe.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
    vimeoVideoList.Add(sourceData);
}
```

Like the above code, is there any way to parse the href links?

My HTML Content is uploaded as a file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ut3ecvny2yXrjH3bz5TPTa-X4FfQ_I4O/view?usp=share_link).

We have a few `href` links on the content, and if we tap on them, the corresponding web page we need to open. Currently if I tap nothing is happening.

If the data tapping is impossible, is there any way to get the href links only as a list?

Comment: Are they relative hrefs?

Comment: Yes @LajosArpad

Comment: Would those values work if they were absolute hrefs? Can you perform a test to check this?

Comment: What do you mean by that? @LajosArpad

Comment: I've updated the question with more details? @LajosArpad

Comment: I mean that you need to try using a full URL as a test and see whether the tapping works. If the answer is yes, then you will need to specify the base page in order to solve the problem. If no, then the problem is something else. We will never know if you do not try it.